# C# and C++ interop

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I have a C++ function defined as

```
#define DllExport   __declspec( dllexport ) 
extern "C" DllExport void _stdcall CppAmp::square_array(float* arr, int n)
```

and c# code

```
[DllImport("C++AmpProject.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        extern unsafe static void square_array(float* array, int length);
```

However I am getting an exception `System.EntryPointNotFoundException`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The function is exported with its decorated name.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check via [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) before use it. Your function may not named like `square_array`

Answer (score -1):

Turns out the argument names must match exactly.

Comment: No, that's not the case